# filter many to many field from a list

Tags: filter, many-to-many

Here are my models

```py
class Subjects (models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    subject_name=models.CharField ()

class Examinations(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    exam_choice=(("Annual ","Annual"),
                 ("First Term","First Term"),
                 ("Second Term","Second Term"),
                 ("December Test","December Test"),
                 ("General Test","General Test"),
    )
    exam_type=models.CharField(choices=exam_choice,max_length=255,default="")
    session_id=models.ForeignKey(SessionYearModel,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjects=models.ManyToManyField(Subjects,related_name='examination',)
```

I want to filter many to many field from a list of subject ids like
and i get one row of exam with id 1

```py
    subject_ids=[2,4,5]
    exams=Examinations.objects.filter(subjects__in=subject_ids)
```

in html template below it display me all subject[1,2,3,4,5,6] related to exam id 1 other than in the list [2,4,5]. I want to display just subject [2,4,5] from many to many fields.

```html
                    {% for exam in exams %}
                    {% for subject in exam.subjects.all %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ exam.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ exam.exam_type }}</td>
                        <td>
                            {{ subject.course_id.course_name}} | {{ subject.subject_name}},
                             </td>
                        <td><a href="{% url 'edit_exam' exam_id=exam.id %}" class="btn btn-success">Edit</a></td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endfor %} 
                      {% endfor %}
```

I tried many ways to do this but in vain. I m stuck here and cannot proceed further

```py
    #examss=Examinations.objects.annotate(count=Count('subjects')).filter(count=len(subject_ids))
    #exams=Examinations.objects.filter(subjects__id__in=subject_ids).annotate(count=Count('subjects')).filter(count=len(subject_ids))
```

but it did not work and displays empty result